# How to combine LIKE and CASE WHEN in SQLite?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, concatenation, wildcard

...Hi, a database ingenue here.  I'm trying to figure out how to use `LIKE` with `CASE` in SQLite, or some equivalent approach.  I've got a **prod_names** table that contains concatenated data--occasionally just 1 item, but usually containing several comma-separated items.  For my new '**Toy**' column, I need to find every record that contains '*CapGun*'.  The code below works only when '*CapGun*' is the only item, and not when there are multiple items (eg, '*BarbieDoll, CapGun, EasyBakeOven*').

```
SELECT 
 customer_id, 
 prod_names,
 CASE prod_names WHEN 'CapGun' THEN 'CG' ELSE 'not_CG' END Toy
FROM
 Toys_table
ORDER BY 
 Toy
```

I've tried various approaches like `WHEN LIKE '%CapGun%'`, `WHEN INSTR(prod_names,'CapGun') > 0`, and `WHEN GLOB '*CapGun*'` but they all return no results or throw a syntax error.
Any suggestions?  I'm sure there must be a simple solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the expanded case syntax:

```
CASE
  WHEN prod_names LIKE '%CapGun%' THEN ...
  ELSE ...
END
```

This lets use any expression as the condition in your `CASE`, including other columns.